# LINQ to SQL: To Attach or Not To Attach

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

So I'm have a *really* hard time figuring out when I should be attaching to an object and when I shouldn't be attaching to an object. First thing's first, here is a small diagram of my (very simplified) object model.

[image: Schema]

In my DAL I create a new DataContext every time I do a data-related operation. Say, for instance, I want to save a new user. In my business layer I create a new user.

```
var user = new User();
user.FirstName = "Bob";
user.LastName = "Smith";
user.Username = "bob.smith";
user.Password = StringUtilities.EncodePassword("MyPassword123");
user.Organization = someOrganization; // Assume that someOrganization was loaded and it's data context has been garbage collected.
```

Now I want to go *save* this user.

```
var userRepository = new RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<UserRepository>();
userRepository.Save(user);
```

Neato! Here is my save logic:

```
public void Save(User user)
{
 if (!DataContext.Users.Contains(user))
 {
  user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
  user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
  user.Disabled = false;

  //DataContext.Organizations.Attach(user.Organization);
  DataContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
 }
 else 
 {
  DataContext.Users.Attach(user);
 }

 DataContext.SubmitChanges();

 // Finished here as well.
 user.Detach();
}
```

So, here we are. You'll notice that I comment out the bit where the DataContext attachs to the organization. If I attach to the organization I get the following exception:

> **NotSupportedException:** *An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an
>   entity that is not new, perhaps having
>   been loaded from another DataContext. 
>   This is not supported.*

Hmm, that doesn't work. Let me try it *without* attaching (i.e. comment out that line about attaching to the organization).

> **DuplicateKeyException:** *Cannot add an entity with a key that is already
>   in use.*

WHAAAAT? I can only assume this is trying to insert a new organization which is obviously false.

So, what's the deal guys? What should I do? What is the proper approach? It seems like L2S makes this quite a bit harder than it should be...

**EDIT:** I just noticed that if I try to look at the pending change set (dataContext.GetChangeSet()) I get the same NotSupportedException I described earlier!! What the hell, L2S?!

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using foreign keys in the database to indicate the relationship in your object model?

Comment: Hmm, I am, I'm in the DB...not sure why they didn't come through in the diagram (i.e. would expect a grey key) but I was under the impression that the little arrow going from one box to the other indicated that there was a foreign key in place.

Comment: You are using L2S not how it is supposed to be used. Normally, Attach is almost never called. Why are you using a repo in the first place? It only seems to restrict what you can do and offer you nothing in return. With L2S, the DataContext *is* the repository.

Answer (score 8):

It may not work exactly like this under the hood, but here's the way I conceptualize it: When you summon an object from a DataContext, one of the things Linq does is track the changes to this object over time so it knows what to save back if you submit changes. If you lose this original data context, the Linq object summoned from it doesn't have the history of what has changed in it from the time it was summoned from the DB.

For example:

```
DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();
User u = db.Users.Single( u => u.Id == HARD_CODED_GUID );
u.FirstName = "Foo";
db.SubmitChanges();
```

In this case since the User object was summoned from the data context, it was tracking all the changes to "u" and knows how to submit those changes to the DB.

In your example, you had a User object that had been persisted somewhere (or passed from elsewhere and do not have it's original DataContext it was summoned from).  In this case, you must attach it to the new data context.

```
User u; // User object passed in from somewhere else
DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();
u.FirstName = "Foo";
DbDataContext.Users.Attach( u );
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Since the relationship between user and organization is just a GUID (OrganizationId) in your data model, you only have to attach the user object.

I'm not sure about your scaffolding code, but maybe something like this:

```
    private const Guid DEFAULT_ORG = new Guid("3cbb9255-1083-4fc4-8449-27975cb478a5");
    public void Save(User user)
    {
        if (!DataContext.Users.Contains(user))
        {
            user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            user.Disabled = false;
            user.OrganizationId = DEFAULT_ORG; // make the foreign key connection just
                                               // via a GUID, not by assigning an
                                               // Organization object

            DataContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
        }
        else
        {
            DataContext.Users.Attach(user);
        }

        DataContext.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

Comment: You need to use the **overload** `Attach(user,true)` To tell Linq2SQL that the model is changed from the original. The thirds overload allows you pass in the original and the modified and it will remap it in the background. Awesome. I still don't understand how Dave Markle used `InsertOnSubmit` to update?

Answer (score 1):

So "attach" is used when you take an object that exists from the database, detach it (say by marshalling it over a webservice somewhere else) and want to put it back into the database.  Instead of calling .Attach(), call .InsertOnSubmit() instead.  You're almost there conceptually, you're just using the wrong method to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...what about in this Parent -> Child relationship that I've got goin' on? If I'm inserting a new child object (i.e. User in the diagram above), do I need to first Attach to the parent object?

Comment: Let me put it this way.  I have written about 5 linq to sql apps now, and have never had to use the Attach() method at all.  You actually don't need to even assign the relationship between the two objects if you don't want to as long as the IDs on the related fields agree.  L2SQL will understand what you mean when you call SubmitChanges().

Comment: Yea. So that inserted an new row with a new ID into the DB. Not sure how you got that to update existing rows using the ID? I got the Object from DBCOntext, changes a few fields, sent the object back to be saved. Niether Attach or InsertOnSubmit() works, unless I delete the old row?

Answer (score 1):

I used an big  table with 400+ columns. No way am I going to map and test all that!

Get the original object from database, and attach it with the amended object. Just make sure the object coming back in is fully populated other wise it will override it the DB with blanks!

Or you can copy the original GET into memory and work on a proper copy (not just reference) of the MOdel, then pass the original and the changed one in, instead of re getting like I do in the example. This is just an example of how it works.

```
public void Save(User user)
{

    if (!DataContext.Users.Contains(user))
    {
        user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        user.Disabled = false;
        user.OrganizationId = DEFAULT_ORG; // make the foreign key connection just
                                           // via a GUID, not by assigning an
                                           // Organization object

        DataContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
    }
    else
    {
        var UserDB = DataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(db => db.id == user.id); //Costs an extra call but its worth it if oyu have 400 columns!
        DataContext.Users.Attach(user, userDB); //Just maps all the changes on the flu
    }

    DataContext.SubmitChanges();

}
```